# How can I take the Wigner transform of an operator with an absolute value?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, wigner-transform

I want to be able to find the Wigner transforms of operators of the form $\Theta(\hat{O})$, where $\Theta$ is the Heaviside function and $\hat{O}$ in general depends on both $x$ and $p$. For the operators of interest, $\tilde{O}$ is known. Since the Wigner transform is linear, I can use the expression $$ \Theta(x)=\frac{1}{2} \frac{\left( |x| - x \right)}{x}$$

Unfortunately, I am no better off than I was when I started, as I can't figure out how get the Wigner transform of the absolute value of an arbitrary operator in terms of the Wigner transform of that operator.

**Is there an expression for the Wigner transform of the absolute value of an operator in terms of the Wigner transform of that same operator?**

**If so, what is it?**

Comment: Comment to the question (v1): The right-hand side of the equation is not the Heavyside step function.

Comment: The most simple would be $W(|\hat O|) = |W(\hat O) |$... It should work at least for simple operators  $\hat O$ like $Q^n$ or  $P^n$.

Comment: @Qmechanic: Sorry! It was a typo.

Answer (score 3):

I don't really have a good answer, so I'll just discuss the obvious "translation" issues involved in the Wigner transform. That is, *once* you have a solution ot the operator problem in Hilbert space, in principle you can map it to phase space, but phase space in itself will not expedite the solution---it will actually make it messier.

The absolute value of the operator $\hat{O}$ is presumably $\sqrt{\hat{O}^\dagger \hat{O}}\equiv \hat{B} $, so the crucial question is what type of algorithm one would choose to evaluate the [square root $\hat{B}$ of the operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/814720/square-root-of-a-hermitian-operator-exists) $\hat{A}=  \hat{O}^\dagger \hat{O}=\hat{B} \hat{B}$.

If, for example, a suitable satisfactory series in  $\hat{A}$  were found for $\hat{B}$, The Weyl symbol/Wigner transform of $\hat{B}$ 
would be $\tilde{B}=$the same star-function of $\tilde{A}$, where, of course, 
$\tilde{A}=\tilde{O}^* \star\tilde{O}$, *in the abstract*. Beyond the above math stack sequence, for a bounded normalized $\hat{A}$, one might consider $\hat{B}= \sqrt{I+(\hat{A}-I)}$ $= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {{1/2}\choose{n}} (\hat{A} -I )^n  $, etc.   Transcription to Wigner transforms would merely replace operator powers by star-powers of Weyl symbols.

Unfortunately, this is merely formally correct, but an impractical setup. Even for (unbounded) $\hat{O}=\hat{x} +i\hat{p}$, finding a bona-fide $\tilde{B}$ is daunting.

One wonders if the $\tanh(k\hat{O})$ representation of the step function for large *k* were more practical, instead, so $|\hat{O}|=\lim_{k\to\infty} \tanh(k\hat{O}) ~\hat{O}$. See, e.g. this [application 266886](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/264243/how-can-we-define-the-distance-for-a-pair-quantum-states-in-phase-space/266886#266886).