# How can we define the distance for a pair quantum states in phase space?

Tags: density-operator, phase-space, wigner-transform, quantum-states

In condensed matter physics, we know that two degenerate ferromagnetic ground states $|\uparrow\uparrow ...\uparrow \rangle$ and $|\downarrow\downarrow...\downarrow\rangle$ are far from each other in phase space because it needs lots of operations to convert one to another.

Is there a quantity like "distance" in phase space to describe such a property?

Comment: For states in the  computational basis https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance

Comment: @fqq , thank you, I think the actual states I am considering are not in the computational basis. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure what you might be after, but I'll assume you want the phase-space analog of the [Trace distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_distance) of two hermitian, normalized density matrices *σ* and *ρ*, that is, half the sum of the absolute values of the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ of their (hermitian) difference, 
$$
T(\rho,\sigma) = \tfrac{1}{2} \operatorname{Tr} \left[ \sqrt{(\rho-\sigma)^2} \right] = \tfrac{1}{2} \sum_i | \lambda_i |   ~.
$$

In phase space, via the Wigner map, the density matrix transforms into (real, normalized) [Wigner functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_quasiprobability_distribution#Definition_and_meaning), and Hilbert space traces into phase space integrals.

Thus you end up with something like 
$$
T(f,g)=\tfrac{1}{2} \int dx dp ~\mid (f(x,p)-g(x,p))\mid_\star ~,
$$
where $\mid f\mid _\star$  may be defined as, for instance,  $\tanh_\star(kf) \star f$, with *k* a positive number, as $k\to \infty$.

For example, the trace distance between the ground state and the first excited state of the [quantum harmonic oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_space_formulation#Simple_harmonic_oscillator) is something like
$$
T(f_0,f_1)=\frac{1}{\pi \hbar} \int dx dp ~\mid  e^{-(x^2+p^2)/\hbar} ( 1-\frac{x^2+p^2}{\hbar}) \mid _\star  = 1~.
$$

In Hilbert/Fock space, the result is trivial, as $\rho=|0\rangle \langle 0|$,  $\sigma=|1\rangle \langle 1|$, and hence *T*=(1+1)/2=1.

In phase space, felicitously, the above integral is computable through a fundamental property of different star-genfunctions of a hamiltonian, their star-orthonormality,  $~f_a\star f_b= \frac{1}{h} \delta_{a,b}~ f_a$, ( [Lemma 4, eqn (25) of CTQMPS](http://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/a.pdf) ).

Consequently,
$$
\tanh_\star k(f_0-f_1) ~\star f_0= \tanh ( k/h) ~ f_0,
$$
$$
\tanh_\star k(f_0-f_1) ~\star f_1= \tanh(- k/h) ~ f_1,
$$
So the large *k* limit yields $\mid f_0-f_1\mid_\star=f_0 +f_1$, and since the stargenstates are normalized, the trace distance reduces to its maximum value,
$$
T=\tfrac{1}{2}\int dx dp (f_0+f_1)=(1+1)/2=1.
$$

References:

*Quantum Computation and Quantum Information*, Michael A Nielsen  & Isaac L Chuang, Cambridge University Press; 10th Anniversary edition (2011) ISBN-13: 978-1107002173

*A Concise Treatise on Quantum Mechanics in Phase Space*, Thomas L Curtright, David B Fairlie, Cosmas K Zachos, World Scientific (2014) ISBN-13: 978-9814520430

---

*Edits*: A different, but related distance measure in Hilbert space is [Heydari's](http://arxiv.org/abs/1503.00238), Section **4.4**. It is less direct to evaluate, but can be translated to phase space, if needs be.

A very different distance measure Wigner-transforms the 
*f-g*-asymmetric distance of Mandilara,Karpov & Cerf, *PhysRev* **A79** (2009) 062302, namely, $\quad \int\! dxdp (f-g)^2 ~/(2\int\! dxdp ~f^2)$. 
For the above oscillator example, this evaluates to 1, by inspection.

Comment: Wow!! Thi has been a delightful read Mr.Zachos. Thank you very much for this post.

Comment: Where in "A Concise Treatise on Quantum Mechanics in Phase Space" may I find the trace wigner fucntion version of the trace distance that you have shared. I would like to learn more about this at a deeper level. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: I fear there is no dedicated section there... The "translation" is self-explanatory once you learn the language...

Comment: I see, have you any idea where a formal proof of this has been written. I'll try to prove it myself, it seems like it should be a straighforward result. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: The representation of the absolute value in phase space functions has been dealt with on this site, but I don't recall where.  I am not sure what precisely you want to see where, and at what depth. You'd best put in a bit of work yourself, and only then ask a narrow question on specific points...

Comment: I have been reading your book on QMPS and at the moment I am on page 30. I was hoping to find out by now what is meant by the subscript $| ...|_{\star}$ that you have used in the Moyal version of absolute value for the Wigner fucntion rendition of the trace distance. I have also seen such subcripts used for the exponential fucntion in various exercises provided by your text book. Would you kindly included a brief not regarding the meaning of $\star$ as a subscript ? This would be highly illuminating. Thank you for your time.

Comment: In particular, how is $\tanh_{\star}$ defined?

Comment: I see, that is what I suspected. Thank you kindly. Your book has been a pleasure to read thus far. Reading the historical introduction brought a smile to my face multiple times. Thank you and your colaborators for such a pleasant read.

Comment: For $\tanh f= f-f^3/3+2f^5/15+...$, you have $\tanh_\star f= f-f\star f\star f/3 +...$.